# navigation controller dosen't work

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

view controller has srollView in storyBoard, I embed it in navigation Controller and add view controllers to the scrollView by `self.scrollView.addSubview((V1?.view)!)` method, the problem is I cant change the navigation controller property, item, color, and other stuff, I cant change it programmatically or in storyBoard it dose appear but I can't change anything and even it's has a dark gray color the normal navigation controller has a light gray color  [image: look here]

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {     


let V1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Broadcast") as UIViewController!

    self.addChildViewController(V1!)
    self.scrollView.addSubview((V1?.view)!)
    V1?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    V1?.view.frame = scrollView.bounds



    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width * 1 , y: self.view.frame.height)
}
```

Comment: Please show some of the code you have been trying to change the navigation bar and where you have placed it.

Comment: see the code up

Comment: That code just shows how you added a child view controller to your main view controller it doesn't show what code you have tried to change the navigation bar properties (font, colour, etc)

Answer (score 0):

you can change navigation bar font, can add content and more easily using storyboard, kindly look at the attached snapshot below:
[image]

I hope you get, what you are searching for.

Comment: i have tried this an even i write it in code not working and you didn't get the question there is a problem here